# List all MySQL tables and exclude specific one

Tags: php, mysql

I try to return all MySQL tables from Database and exclude specific one for example with users.  I use following code to print my table names:

```
function findTables() {
    global $conn;
    global $DB;

    $query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $DB ";
    $showTablesFromDb = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($showTablesFromDb)) {
        echo "<li><a href='admin.php?show={$row[0]}'>{$row[0]}</a></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Code above show all tables and its nice but during proces i want exclude one particular table from loop - for example users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution will be :

```
show tables where tables_in_$DB not like 'a%';
```

Here are some demos:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_test3 |
+-----------------+
| a1              |
| t1              |
| t2              |
+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

-- LIKE is simpler than NOT LIKE
mysql> show tables like 'a%';
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_test3 (a%) |
+----------------------+
| a1                   |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- `show tables not like 'a%'` is not working, 
-- use the following way for NOT LIKE matching
mysql> show tables where tables_in_test3 not like 'a%';
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_test3 |
+-----------------+
| t1              |
| t2              |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Fair enough - but correct query is: 
'SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_$DB NOT LIKE $database_name' . Anyway thank you for a hint - i mark it as accepted

Comment: Thanks, I knew that `show tables like 'a%'` works, and then assumed that NOT LIKE works too. Was in a hurry at that time. I just updated the post, with more info and demo.

Answer (score 2):

If the above answer doesn't work, try this:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM $DB WHERE Tables_in_$DB NOT LIKE 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by creating a table that contains the tables you don't want like this:
`show tables where tables_in_yourDBName not in(select * from disallowed_tables);`

---

The value of the column in disallowed_tables is plain varchar.